# ListView Footerview not taking full width

Tags: android

This is my footerview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_add_location1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top_10"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="+ Add more location"
        android:textColor="@color/grey3"
        android:textSize="@dimen/size_15" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Heres how I am inflating my listView footerview

```
 View footerView1 = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.layout_footerview1, null);
        listView1.addFooterView(footerView1);
```

The footerView i.e the button is not taking the width as match_parent rather it is taking the width to be wrap_content.

Please Help me in acheiving my result. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why you are using weight for single view in `LinearLayout`  simply use `match_parent` for button

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_add_location1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top_10"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="+ Add more location"
        android:textColor="@color/grey3"
        android:textSize="@dimen/size_15" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have tried using this also, but it is not working. Anyways, I resolved the problem, I was using the custom listview. Upon deep looking on the codes of custom listview, i found that its height and width are set to wrap content, I just changed its width size to match_parent, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

you should try without some properties, and
 set `ListView`'s height and width `fill_parent`.

 like `android:weightSum="1"` etc

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_add_location1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+ Add more location"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

if still not working you should try with setting the padding in java like..

```
View footer = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.footer_button,
            null);
    footer.setPadding(100, 0, 100, 0);//first is for left and secon 100 for right.
```

Comment: I have tried using this also, but it is not working.

Comment: I resolved the problem, I was using the custom listview. Upon deep looking on the codes of custom listview, i found that its height and width are set to wrap content, I just changed its width size to match_parent, and it worked. Thanks for the solution.